# Changing LDAP datastore config from OpenAM SDK

Tags: encryption, ldap, single-sign-on, openam, opensso

When changing datastore configuration using OpenAM SDK, anything works well except the password. The password resets to empty string, even if I give the related attributes "sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-authpw". I tried many cases: removing the field from attributes, and giving a 'set' of strings. none of them made my password intact!

Here is part of my code:

```
fun setDataStoreConfig(realmName: String, storeName: String, newAttrs: Map<*,*>) {
  val srvConf = ServiceConfigManager(IdConstants.REPO_SERVICE, getUserSSOToken())
  val orgConf = srvConf.getOrganizationConfig(realmName, null)
  val subConf = orgConf.getSubConfig(storeName)
  val attrs =  subConf.attributes
  attrs.putAll(newAttrs)
  attrs["sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-authpw"]=setOf("*********")
  subConf.attributes = attrs
}
```

Comment: Apparently, when saving this information into Directory Service, some salt is added! I am not sure the salt is added by OpenAM or the OpenDJ itself! Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ClientSDK and the OpenAM server must use the same encryption key (am.encryption.pwd property in AMConfig.properties on the ClientSDK side).

Please keep in mind that the ClientSDK is deprecated and its usage in new deployments is strongly discouraged.

Comment: I have no choice! OpenAM 13 is buggy (Must use OpenDJ 3 that is buggy!) I am using OpenAM 12 and for such actions there is no RESTful API!

Comment: Your solution fixed my problem! Really thanks! I wasted about 2 work days and at the end temporarily fixed the problem by reserving password from Directory Service and restoring it again using OpenDJ SDK! But now I fixed the problem and revmoved the dirty DS code!